# projecting LaTeX onto a plane not just text onto a plane pst-solides3d

Tags: fonts, pstricks, pst-solides3d

I am able to project text

```
\psSolid[oject=text, text = zyz]
```

but want put what would be in LaTeX `$\alpha$` as the text. `\psProjection` prints verbatim: `$\alpha$`.

Is it possible to force the LaTeX?

Here is a slightly modified example from the [`pst-solides3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,5)
  \psset{unit=0.5}
  \psset{solidmemory}
  \psSolid[object=cube,a=8,action=draw,name=A,linecolor=red]%
  \psset{fontsize=100}
  \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 0,name=P0]
  \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=$\alpha$,plan=P0]%
  \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 1,name=P1]
  \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=$\beta$,plan=P1]%
  \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 4,name=P4]
  \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=$\epsilon$,plan=P4]%
  \axesIIID(4,4,4)(6,6,6)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course I can do this. I need to see the Greek symbols alpha beta etc and maybe kets |0>

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psset{unit=0.5}
    \psSolid[object=cube,a=8,action=draw,name=A,linecolor=red]%
    \psset{fontsize=150,PSfont=Symbol}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 0,name=P0]
    \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=a,plan=P0]%
    \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 1,name=P1]
    \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=b,plan=P1]%
    \psSolid[object=plan,action=none,definition=solidface,args=A 4,name=P4]
    \psProjection[object=texte,linecolor=red,text=e,plan=P4]%
    \axesIIID(4,4,4)(6,6,6)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it says don't say "thanks" but it human. Thank you.

Comment: @paul if you want to say thanks, please upvote and accept the answer (up arrow and tick on the left hand side of then answer.

Comment: I note the thanks protocol. While this approach provides a fix for simple expressions it would not do for more adorned Symbols  eg x_{ij} So the answer seems to be that one cannot PROJECT LaTeX expressions unless perhaps they were preprocessed to a string of Symbols. Perhaps there are some clues how to force this by looking in the pst-3D package. I will have a look.